# Is it possible to have a zero article in front of a count noun

Tags: articles

I am trying to write a contract. This is what I am trying to write:

> Instructor must ensure a clean, tidy and well-lit teaching environment.

Maybe I am overthinking things but should I add an article in front of the word "Instructor?" I am not talking about any specific instructor so I assume the is out of the question. At the same time, a sounds weird to my ear as well. What is the rule here?

Comment: It would be normal to use _the_, meaning _the person who has the post of instructor_.

Comment: It depends on the type of a contract. If it is an employee  contract under the Labour Law, then it is usually 'the Instructor.' There are much more determiners than the two of them mentioned. Determiners show that a word is a noun and qualify its semantic properties in addition. E. g., the word 'every' is a determiner too. Absent article is a determiner also. Just change the word 'instructor' to the plural form.

Comment: The title of your question is actually asking something different than the body of your question. Is it *possible*? Yes. But the count noun has to be plural. *I **ate scallops** when I was in Boston.*

Comment: I believe that is not always the case. For example some proper noun is never preceded by an article. For example , “Canada is a beautiful country” I guess what I want to figure out is if the zero article can be followed by ordinary noun as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The" is the right choice here (and throughout the contract) You mean "the instructor who has signed the contract".

It is possible that another determiner could be more appropriate: For example if the contract is between you and a company that provides many instructors you might say "Each instructor" or use a plural: "Instuctors must"

But the most likely case is "The".